# Cannot access io object in session.socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, express, socket.io

I am using `session.socket.io` for my app

```
o = require('socket.io').listen(tmpServer),
appCookieParser = express.cookieParser(settings.cookie.secret),
appRedisStore = new RedisStore(),
sessionIO = new SessionSockets(io, appRedisStore, appCookieParser

App.app.use(appCookieParser)
App.app.use(express.session({
    store: appRedisStore
}))
```

Note that `App` is a global variable which holds some of my app data and some helper functions, as I followed the [LearnAllTheNodes](https://github.com/LearnAllTheNodes) application structure.

Then I define the callback on `connection`

```
sessionIO.on('connection', socketHandler)
```

where `socketHandler` is a function returned by a `require` call.

```
module.exports = function(err, socket, session) {
   console.log(io.sockets.clients('a'))
   socket.join('a')
   console.log(io.sockets.clients('a'))
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) I should have access to my `io` object, but I am always getting the error that `io` is not defined.

Note that if I am emitting some events or listening for some events in the `sockatHandler` I  am getting/sending them properly. Just I have no access to `io`.

**UPDATE**

It turns out it works perfectly if I am implementing the callback function as an anonymous function. The documentation is confusing, it should be: you can use `io` if you have a reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my app less crowded I've updated the `socketHandler` so it takes all my socket related objects

```
socketHandler(sessionIO, io)
```

and I am handling the socket operations in another module via these objects.

Comment: Look at my example, that's exactly what I do (see [there](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/main.js#L384)).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have forgotten to define `io` which here should be the listener.

According to the code you display, you should probably have something like

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio.listen(server);
```

[Here's an example of a complete application using express, socket.io and session.socket.io.](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/ws.js)

Comment: I did not post all my app code. But I'll update it. I did not forgot.

Comment: Thanks, nice example though :)